# how can i have a url hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i have the url link to a website and not just show as unlinked text? I have pasted the json below and the on click script below that! I have info i want to show up on click and i want the info "description" to be a live link. I'm a beginner, sorry about the syntax :/

```
json:
{
  "features": [

    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Simply Pure",
        "description": "simplypure.com"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [-105.0113291,39.7619213,0],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    },

  ],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

and this is the script:

```
<script>
     

      map.on('click', function (e) {
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
          layers: ['test-two'] // replace this with the name of the layer
        });

        if (!features.length) {
          return;
        }

        var feature = features[0];

        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
          .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
          .setHTML(
            '<h3>' +
              feature.properties.title +
              '</h3><p>' +
              feature.properties.description +
              '</p>'
          )
          .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
          .addTo(map);


      });
    </script>
```

Comment: errr, nothing to do with json.....   if you want a link  it needs to be a <a href="..." />

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the HTML `<a>` tag to create a hyperlink. Learn more about the `a` tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

```
<script>
     

      map.on('click', function (e) {
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
          layers: ['test-two'] // replace this with the name of the layer
        });

        if (!features.length) {
          return;
        }

        var feature = features[0];

        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
          .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
          .setHTML(
            '<h3>' +
              feature.properties.title +
              '</h3><a href="' + feature.properties.description + '">' +
              feature.properties.description +
              '</a>'
          )
          .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
          .addTo(map);


      });
    </script>
```